# Django Web Application Access Active Directory

Tags: django, python-3.x, active-directory, windows-authentication, ldap3

I am trying to get user's Active Directory information on the local intranet network, from an Django Web Application.

> What I want: ** When Users/Client log on to the website, they can see their various details from the Active Directory **

If the users have already entered their username and password when turning on their PCs. So they shouldn't need to do it again.

How can I make it so that users are able to enter their website without entering their username and password?

Comment: look more into sessions and cookies

Comment: @Vaibhav could you please give a more detailed approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django project has a Remote-Auth middleware: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/auth-remote-user/

This Q from 2014 talks to using this with Python 2.7 (and I'd expect Django 1.x), but I can't see this changing too quickly from previous versions:
[Django authenticate using logged in windows domain user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881344/django-authenticate-using-logged-in-windows-domain-user)